# Mapping image to world coordinates, but getting homography matrix as a singular non invertible matrix

Tags: matrix, computer-vision, camera-calibration, camera-intrinsics

I am trying to map image coordinates to world coordinates for a particular dataset. I have the camera parameters available (both intrinsic and extrinsic). According to the equation, I need to take an inverse of the Homography matrix. However, when I try to do so, it fails as the Homography matrix for the camera turns out to be singular (non invertible).

H = K [ r1 | r2 | T ]

p<sup>(img)</sup> = H x p<sup>(w)</sup>

p<sup>(w)</sup> = H<sup>-1</sup> x p<sup>(img)</sup>

The reason for using this form of Homography matrix is that I am finding Road coordinates, hence Z=0
Here, x is sign for matrix multiplication, H is the homography, K is the Intrinsic matrix, T is the Translational matrix , r1 and r2 are the first and second columns of the Rotational Matrix. p<sup>(img)</sup> are the image coordinates and p<sup>(img)</sup> are the world coordinates.

Getting values for the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters (https://github.com/ori-mrg/robotcar-dataset-sdk/blob/master/models/stereo_narrow_left.txt)

The homography matrix we get is singular: [Homography matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyWcV.png)

Is there another way to map image to world coordinates?

Comment: you haven't shown how you calculate that damaged matrix. -- that text file you link to appears to contain fx, fy, cx, cy, and then a 4x4 transformation matrix that swaps some axes around. did you notice that?

Comment: I have used fx, fy, cx, and cy to calculate K (intrinsics). The 4x4 matrix are the extrinsics that give us R1, R2 and T. Thats how I came up with the Homography Matrix

Comment: the extrinsic matrix pans the camera away from its original view *entirely*. there will be no overlap of those views at all. what were you expecting to see? -- I would say the equations are questionable. it's been a long while since I last dealt with this stuff (breaking 3D/4x4 down to 2D/3x3) so I can't put my finger on it. check your [r1|r2|T]. is that singular already?